# How to combine an index "prefix" to the data in a Pandas series? Does one create a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series:

```
import pandas 
ser = pd.Series(...)
ser

idx1     23421535123415135
idx2     98762981356281343
idx3     394123942916498173
idx4     41234189756983411
...
idx50    123412938479283419
```

I would like to combined the index append to the front of each data row. The output I'm looking for is:

```
idx1 23421535123415135
idx2 98762981356281343
idx3 394123942916498173
idx4 41234189756983411
...
idx50 123412938479283419
```

This could either be a pandas Series (where the array is naturally indexed) or a numpy array.

For a dataframe, in order to combine two columns, you use:

```
df["newcolumn"] = df[['columnA','columnB']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

but I'm confused how to accomplish this with a pandas series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you start with your Series:

```
 In [34]: s = pd.Series(data=[1, 2], index=['idx0', 'idx1'])
```

Then you can do

```
In [35]: t = s.reset_index()

In [36]: t['index'].astype(str) + ' ' + t[0].astype(str)
Out[36]: 
0    idx0 1
1    idx1 2
dtype: object
```

Note that if you don't need to introduce the space in between, it's shorter:

```
In [37]: s.reset_index().astype(str).sum(axis=1)
Out[37]: 
0    idx01
1    idx12
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pandas.series.str.cat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) :

```
In[8]:ser
Out[8]: 
idx0     23421535123415135
idx1     98762981356281343
idx2    394123942916498173
idx3     41234189756983411
dtype: int64

In[9]:ser=pd.Series(ser.index.astype(str).str.cat(ser.astype(str),' '))

In[10]:ser
Out[10]: 
0     idx0 23421535123415135
1     idx1 98762981356281343
2    idx2 394123942916498173
3     idx3 41234189756983411
dtype: object
```